# What is the meaning of php phrase?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I study Laravel framework source code. I reach the following command.

```
class Application extends Container implements ApplicationContract, HttpKernelInterface
{


    public function handle(SymfonyRequest $request, $type = self::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
    {
        return $this[HttpKernelContract::class]->handle(Request::createFromBase($request));
    }


}
```

So, I need to know the meaning of **$this[MyClass:class]->someMethod()** phrase in php syntax.

Is `$this` array?! How?

Thanks

Comment: $this is the object here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `Application` extends `Container` which itself implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), so `$this[HttpKernelContract::class]` essentially calls `$this->offsetGet(HttpKernelContract::class)` which should be implemented in `Container`.